# current_user helper returning error in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Devise and in my show view I have:

`<%= link_to "Profile", current_user %>`

When accessing the view, I get the error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show"} missing required keys: [:id]`

My show method (suggested by a very helpful SO member):

```
  def show
    if params[:id]
      if current_user
        @user = current_user
      else
        flash[:notice] = "This page is not available"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    else
      @user = current_user
    end
  end
```

My routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => '', :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout',
                                      :password => 'password', :confirmation => 'verification',
                                      :unlock => 'unblock', :registration => 'signup',
                                      :sign_up => 'new' }

    get   'login' => 'users/login'

  devise_scope :user do
    get   'login',          to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'users/login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get   'logout',         to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
    get   'signup',         to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get   'password',       to: 'devise/passwords#new'
    match 'users/secret',   to: "devise/passwords#create",      via: :post
    match 'sessions/user',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',       via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
    match 'users/signup',   to: 'devise/registrations#create',  via: :post
  end

  #resources :users
  #resources :users
resources :sessions

# Authenticated Users:
authenticated :user do
  root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root
end 

# Non-Authenticated Users
root to: 'site#index'

get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
get 'edit', to: 'users#edit', as: 'user/edit'
```

Any ideas why the current_user helper is returning the error?

Comment: What about `user_path(current_user)`?

Comment: Same error, but now it references `user_path(current_user)`.

Comment: There's no route for an unauthenticated user...  Are you signed in when you try to access this path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error when you access the view as an unauthenticated visitor because the current_user is nil and there is no route corresponding to user_path(nil).  The easiest fix, although not necessarily one I'd recommend, is to change this line in config/routes.rb:

```
get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

to

```
get 'profile', to: 'users#show', as: 'profile'
```

and then update the view to

```
<%= link_to "Profile", (current_user ? user_path(current_user) : profile_path) %>
```

A more complex (but in my opinion architecturally superior option) is to pull all of the no-id logic out of your users controller into a profile controller that has an index method like:

```
class ProfileController
  before_filter :check_authentication, only: [:index]

  def check_authentication
    unless current_user
      flash[:notice] = "This page is not available"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def index
    @user = current_user
    render 'users/show'
  end
end
```

and then you'd add a matching route and update your link to point to this action.

The users show method you've written essentially ignores the params[:id], which means it's really not a show method.  It ALWAYS shows the page for the current_user, regardless of which id is passed in.  This ProfileController reflects that.

Then the users show method becomes a bare-bones show method again that just looks up by id, which is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: You should confirm that current_user is not nil.  It's hard to see how you'd get that error otherwise.

Comment: How would I do that? That's the issue.

Comment: Replace the profile line in the view with `<%= current_user.nil? 'Current User is nil' : "Current User is #{current_user.id}" %>

Comment: Sorry -  `<%= current_user.nil? ? 'Current User is nil' : "Current User is #{current_user.id}" %>`

Comment: Great.  Now update it to `%= current_user.nil? ? 'Current User is nil' : "User path is #{user_path(current_user)}" %>` and see if it errors out.  If that's the case, then it's probably because of this line - `get '', to: 'users#show', as: 'user'` in the routes.

Comment: It does, indeed, return the original error. That line in the routes was suggested so as to only allow logged in users to access their show  page at example.com, instead of example.com/users or .../users/1.

Comment: @user1034672 As I tried to make clear in my answer, I think the whole approach taken there is flawed.  You're trying to build a profile controller that works off the current_user.  So build that - don't try and twist the users show action to that purpose.

Comment: Hmm. I understand. However, surely there must be a way to use Devise and a single Users Controller that will allow for show pages at example.com, instead of example.com/users/1 or exmaple.com/user. Is a second Profiles Controller really necessary?

Comment: Devise is being used in the proposed solution.  As for the UsersController, you could absolutely add some logic to check authorization (replacing the current, badly broken code) and include the user_id in the request.  But why?  You've now inherently opened up a security issue you need to address (and thus can potentially break), need to pass a value (id) you don't want to use, and closed off that route/controller for an actually user show route in the future.  Does that sound like a good choice?  That you're using non-standard routes/actions should hint that this approach is questionable.

Comment: So you're saying that you suggest I abandon my proposed url structure and instead use the standard routes/actions of /users/1?

Comment: Yes.  As you've written it you're inherently breaking `/users/1`, `/users/2`, etc.  because you're trying to ignore the id parameter.  If the current_user has id `12345` you're trying to serve up what would normally be `/users/12345` for all of those URLs.  In other words, you're breaking REST - a strong hint that the proposed approach is a bad idea.

Comment: I get it. As an aside, to make the route /partners/, I can use `as: ...` in the routes while a Users Controller exists? You've been extremely helpful. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Happy to help.  I don't really understand the aside though - maybe you should open it up as another question and provide more detail.

Comment: So now I have in the Users Controller: `@user = User.find(params[:id])` and in the routes I removed the two problematic lines and replaced with `resources :users`. In my view I have `<%= link_to "Profile", current_user %>` again. Now I'm getting the error: `Couldn't find User without an ID`. Upon log in I'm sent to example.com (because of `authenticated :user do root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root end`. Going to /users/1 shows the view properly.

Comment: Nothing you've described in this last comment sounds like what I recommended.  Use the ProfileController, set up a route for the ProfileController, and have your link point to that route.  Why are you still using the UsersController for this?

Comment: Agghh. I can't wrap my head around this. If I'm going to stick with the convention of REST, why do I still need the Profile Controller? Is the Users Controller not sufficient?

Comment: It's pretty clear you don't understand why the solution you originally proposed is utterly non-RESTful.  I've attempted to explain, but it doesn't seem to be getting through.  I suggest you read up on REST and try to understand why using a show route and ignoring the id in it is a bad idea and very contrary to REST architecture.  You need the ProfileController because you are not asking to see the resource for any particular user based on their id, but rather for the current_user (who should not be able to access any other user based on their id).

Comment: I wasn't being clear. I meant that I'm abandoning my initial idea; now, I'm planning on using just the Users Controller (with /users/1) to stay RESTful. I'm saying, in that instance, a Profile Controller is not necessary, correct?

Comment: Using `/users/1` does not automatically make you RESTful.  All of my earlier comments apply.  Again, I think you need to read up on REST.  If you're using the current_user's id to define what user is displayed - either by ignoring the id param or by adding some authorization restriction so that the request 401s if the id param doesn't match current_user.id - using `/users/:id` is no more RESTful than defining a profile endpoint and using that as `/profile`.  And the latter has the advantage of not opening up potential security holes.

Comment: Ok...I'll do some more reading. Pardon me, for the relentless questions. Again, thanks a lot.